What's with "proper grammar" requirements?
I was just trying to post a question to Chinese.SE and was blocked constantly on basis of not meeting grammar requirements. I am totally nonplussed as to why an automated system is being used to check my grammar in any way, however rudimentary, since that just sounds like a recipe for mistakes and bugs.
For this question, I had to enter a fake question and then edit it to include the dialogue between my friend and I, because the IM exchange simply did not meet "grammar requirements." The end result is the question actually being worse than it was when I started, largely because of the frustration resulting from me constantly editing it but receiving a red error with zero indication of specifically what was wrong.
I strongly feel that if I'm going to be blocked on basis of grammar, it needs to tell me WHERE the problem is. Imagine working in an IDE that just said "something's wrong with your program somewhere!" and nothing else!!

Because it's global to all SE sites, not Chinese.SE.

The same grammar check is in use on all SE sites.

Oh god I Forgot about that change. Can you migrate the question for me?

Wait, why does it not belong on MSO? Am I not being clear about the part where it's incidental that this happened on Chinese.SE? @bluefeet ?
